# Can't install pytest

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

Tried to run

```
pip install -U pytest
```

from the command prompt, but got this:

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by ‘ProxyError(‘Cannot connect to proxy.’, OSError(‘Tunnel connection failed: 407 authenticationrequired’))’: /simple/pytest/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by ‘ProxyError(‘Cannot connect to proxy.’, OSError(‘Tunnel connection failed: 407 authenticationrequired’))’: /simple/pytest/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by ‘ProxyError(‘Cannot connect to proxy.’, OSError(‘Tunnel connection failed: 407 authenticationrequired’))’: /simple/pytest/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by ‘ProxyError(‘Cannot connect to proxy.’, OSError(‘Tunnel connection failed: 407 authenticationrequired’))’: /simple/pytest/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by ‘ProxyError(‘Cannot connect to proxy.’, OSError(‘Tunnel connection failed: 407 authenticationrequired’))’: /simple/pytest/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pytest (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pytest
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.
```

what does it mean?

My python version is 3.11.1

Comment: You seem to have issues with your proxy

Comment: @rochard4u what proxy? how to test this proxy? my system proxy?

Comment: yes, your system proxy and it the error message is quite clear: `Tunnel connection failed: 407 authenticationrequired`